# Is there something wrong with this proof of the cancellation rule?

Tags: proof-verification, real-numbers

I was helping a friend of mine with math homework. We were dealing with real numbers, and had to prove the cancellation rule; that is $$a,b,c, \in \mathbb{R} \land a+c=b+c \implies a=c$$

He had a little trouble and came up with this proof:
let $a+c=z$, then $z=b+c$ too by the transitive property; obviously $z-c=z-c$ by reflexivity. Using the relation $z=a+c$ for the RHS and the relation $z=b+c$ for the LHS we obtain $ (a+c)-c=(b+c)-c$, by associative property, $a+(c-c)=b+(c-c)$, and consequently $a=b$.

I felt that there was some logical flaw in this proof, but I couldn't pinpoint the mistake. I showed him the standard way to prove the statement but I believe it will be more instructive to understand were he (we) might have gone wrong.

Comment: There aren't any flaws in your proof, but it's phrasing could be improved. Typically you don't need to be so formal as to mention transitivity and reflexivity; you can go straight from $a + c = b + c$ to $(a + c) - c = (b + c) - c$ by substitution without creating a new variable. But what you should include are the steps (associativity, identity) to get from $(a + c) - c = (b + c) - c$ to $a = b$. Normally that would also be unnecessarily formal but not when you're being asked to prove cancellation.

Comment: Such an elementary fact is dependent on what you mean exactly with $+, \mathbb R$, etc. Were you given some axioms for $\mathbb R$ or did you construct $\mathbb R$? If the former, what axioms? If the latter, how do you define $\mathbb R$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ was defined using field axioms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that here the key axiom is that $(R,+)$ is a commutative group, and specifically that $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists an "inverse" with respect the sum operation (the opposite of $c$) that we name $-c$ such that $c+(-c)=0$, being $0$ the neutral element for the sum.
So,  to detail any pass of the proof, you can write something as:
$$
a+c=b+c \iff (a+c)+(-c)=(b+c)+(-c) \iff 
$$
$$
\iff a+(c+(-c))=b+(c+(-c)) \iff a+0=b+0 \iff a=b
$$